# Initial conditions for which these two recursive sequences converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

The following problem is a generalization of an exercise that the professor give me and that I have already solved. In the initial statement $\alpha=0$ and given $0<a_0<1$, the limit of the first sequence  is $\dfrac{a_0}{1-a_0}$. I was wondering what happen if I change a bit the exercise, with $\alpha>1$ it seems to me that the sequence diverges, but what happens if $0<\alpha<1$?

Given $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0<\alpha<1$, we define for each $0\leq n \leq N-1$
$$a_{n+1,N}=a_{n,N}+\dfrac{1}{N}a_{n,N}^2\left(\dfrac{2}{b_{n,N}}\right)^\alpha\\
b_{n+1,N}=b_{n,N}-\dfrac{1}{N}a_{n,N}^2\left(\dfrac{2}{b_{n,N}}\right)^\alpha.$$

There exist any values of $a_0=a_{0,N}$ and $b_0=b_{0,N}$ such that the sequences $\{a_{N,N}\}$ and $\{b_{N,N}\}$ converge to positive numbers?

Attempt: I have realized that $a_N+b_N=a_0+b_0$ for every $N$, so it suffices to see that $\{b_{N,N}\}$ is bounded below or $\{a_{N,N}\}$ is bounded above. I don't know how to make rigorous calculations, but I have found out by using the software Mathematica that apparently  with $\alpha=1/2$ there is convergence for some pairs $(a_0,b_0)$ like

- $a_0=0.004; b_0=0.003$
- $a_0=0.008 ; b_0=0.004$
- $a_0=0.003 ; b_0=0.001$
- $a_0=0.32 ; b_0=0.24$
- $a_0=0.021 ; b_0=0.017$

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you are more likely to get a good answer if you explain why this problem is interesting, i.e., the context. If you solve this problem, then what will you be able to conclude?

Comment: Done :D. This question is a small change of an exercise that I have already solved. I regret deeply. I regret having made this modification because now this problem keeps me awake at night.

Comment: could you check if pairs $a_0, b_0$ where sequences converge forms some kind of dense set, maybe a plot of pairs that converge would help?

Comment: @user376343 We want to know the limit of the sequences $\{a_{N,N}\}$ and $\{b_{N,N}\}$. Each term of these sequences is given by a recurrence law where we have to calculate $a_{1,N},a_{2,N},...,a_{N-1,N}$  to know $a_{N,N}$ (resp. for $b$).

Comment: @quester Good idea. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. The relevant system of differential equations is

$$\frac{df}{dt} = f(t)^2\sqrt{\frac{2}{g(t)}}$$

$$\frac{dg}{dt} = -f(t)^2\sqrt{\frac{2}{g(t)}}.$$

Note $f(t)+g(t)$ is constant, so $g(t) = f(0)+g(0)-f(t)$. Let $d = f(0)+g(0)$ for ease.

$$\frac{df}{dt} = f(t)^2\sqrt{\frac{2}{d-f(t)}}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{d-f}}{f^2}df = \sqrt{2}dt$$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}f(t)\sqrt{1-\frac{f(t)}{d}}\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{f(t)}{d}}}{1-\sqrt{1-\frac{f(t)}{d}}}\right)-d+f(t)}{f(t)\sqrt{d-f(t)}} = \sqrt{2}\cdot t +C.$$

The value of $C$ is obtained by plugging in $0$.

For $f(0)=a_0=0.008$ and $g(0)=b_0=0.004$ (so $d=0.012$), we see (by Mathematica, for instance) that $$\lim_{N \to \infty} a_{N,N} = f(1) \approx 0.0100782$$ and so $$\lim_{N \to \infty} b_{N,N} = g(1) = d-f(1) \approx 0.0019218.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand the relation between the sequneces and the system of ODEs. Can you explain it?

Comment: Fix $N$. Let $f(n/N) = a_{n,N}$ for $0 \le n \le N$. Then $\frac{f((n+1)/N)-f(n/N)}{1/N} = f(n/N)^2\sqrt{2/g(n/N)}$ (where $g(n/N) := b_{n,N}$). The LHS looks like a derivative. I hope it's clear how the ODE naturally comes from this. It would take more time to prove things rigorously, but I honestly just went off of intuition (and then checked the answers agreed with simulations). I can try a proof though if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks. And a last question: How can we deduce the values of $(a_0,b_0)$ for which there is convergence?

Comment: @mathlife have you tried figuring that out from the posted solution?

Comment: I imagine that there will be convergence for the pairs $(a_0,b_0)$ for which $f(t)\leq d$ in $[0,1]$. But I don't know how to deduce it from the implicit expression of $f$.

Comment: @mathlife I think it is homogeneous in $d$ actually... I.e., you can call $f(t)/d$ one variable.

Comment: Ok. I am going to try to deduce it. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131219/discussion-between-mathlife-and-mathworker21).